# Use group by and order by at same time

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables

```
Class(ID,Name)
Month(ID,Name)
Student(ID,Name)
Examination(ID,Student,Class,Month,TotalMarks,ObtainedMarks)
```

the columns `student,class,month` have been taken as a reference in `Examination` table.

I want to select records from `Examination` table `order by ObtanedMarks and Group by Class`

I have used Following SQL Query

```
SELECT     Months.Name, Class.Name AS Classname, Students.Name AS Studentname, Examination.*
FROM         Class INNER JOIN
                      Examination ON Class.ID = Examination.Class INNER JOIN
                      Months ON Examination.Month = Months.ID INNER JOIN
                      Students ON Examination.Student = Students.ID
                      order by Obtained desc Group by Class.Name
```

but the query is not working for me.

Comment: **What** isn't working?

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Which database server are you using and what error messages are you seeing?

Comment: You are only grouping by one column, but the other columns are not aggregate functions.

Comment: If you want to get real help, you should specify some sample input and the output you expect. As it is now, there exist several possible solutions, depending on the final shape of the data you want to have.

Comment: Did the below help out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like its the wrong way round, `Group By` comes before `Order By`.  You either need to include **all** the columns you want to display in the `Group By`, or use an aggregate function, `Sum`, `Max` etc on the fields that are not in the `Group By` clause.

See updated query...

```
SELECT  Months.Name ,
        Class.Name AS Classname ,
        Students.Name AS Studentname ,
        E.Student ,
        E.Class ,
        E.[Month] ,
        E.TotalMarks ,
        E.ObtainedMarks
FROM    Class
        INNER JOIN Examination E ON Class.ID = E.Class
        INNER JOIN Months ON E.[Month] = Months.ID
        INNER JOIN Students ON E.Student = Students.ID
GROUP BY Class.Name ,
        Months.Name ,
        Students.Name ,
        E.Student ,
        E.Class ,
        E.[Month] ,
        E.TotalMarks ,
        E.ObtainedMarks
ORDER BY Obtained DESC
```

Comment: What about the aggregate functions?

Comment: That is an invalid use of the `GROUP BY` operator and will produce an error message with any standard compliant SQL database

Comment: This query is showing error:Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Months.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ... and if you told anyone what database you were using and/or what the error was, they'd stand a chance of helping you.

Comment: i am using sql serbver 2008

Comment: I was editing, I just first added the query in the correct order.

Comment: One more thing I have a column Academic_Year in Exmaination Table.I want to select rows where Academic_Year is 2013-2014..For that i used where clause but it is not working Would u please help me  here